# Sorted map with custom comparator

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a sorted map with a composite key. If it didn't need to be sorted, I would use

```kotlin
val myMap = mapOf(
    Pair(1,"a") to "A",
    Pair(2,"a") to "AA",
    Pair(1,"b") to "B"
)
```

But it has to be a sorted map and this doesn't work:

```kotlin
val myMap = sortedMapOf(
    Pair(1,"a") to "A",
    Pair(2,"a") to "AA",
    Pair(1,"b") to "B"
)
```

What's the most idiomatic way to create a sorted map with a custom comparator? I want it to compare by the first element of the pair and then by the second.

Comment: (A comment coz I don't have time to write the code…) There are two approaches to this. One is to use `Pair`, or similar, as the key, and provide a `Comparator` — Silvio's answer demonstrates this. The other is to use a key object which has a natural ordering (i.e. implements `Comparable`) — which means writing your own Pair-like class. That second approach may take slightly more code — but it has other advantages (such as being able to compare the keys yourself with `>` etc.), so is worth considering. See also [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/natural-order-for-pair-and-triple/16323).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sortedMapOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-map-of.html) has an overload that takes a comparator as its first argument.

```
val myMap = sortedMapOf(
  compareBy<Pair<Int, String>> { it.first } then compareBy { it.second },
  Pair(1,"a") to "A",
  Pair(2,"a") to "AA",
  Pair(1,"b") to "B",
)
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add a lambda example so OP and future readers could have more guidance

Comment: Ah, thanks! I hadn't spotted that overload. There are so many functions in which a lambda parameter comes last, that I oversaw this one which has a lambda that comes first.